# Is flipping bound allowed in a summation operator?

Tags: summation, notation

$$y=\sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{k=i+1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{i^2+j^2} \rfloor} 1$$
Is this a valid and legit expression?

The bounds of $i$ and $j$ are fine, but $k$'s summation has flipping bound.

For example, when $i=1$, the bound of $\sum_{k=i+1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{i^2+j^2} \rfloor}$ becomes $\sum_{2}^{1}$, $\sum_{2}^{2}$ and $\sum_{2}^{3}$.
How is it evaluated in this case?

Or do I have to split the $i$ and $j$ summations to multiple terms so that $i+1$ is always smaller than $\lfloor \sqrt{i^2+j^2} \rfloor$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "flipping bound" you mean that you have some expressions $\sum_{k=a}^b f(k)$ where $a>b$, then it usually works out best to treat such an expression as 0. Whether it actually works depends on your context, of course.

Comment: In my case, the flipping bound means that the lower bound becomes larger than upper bound only at certain iterations, and hence I called it "flipping". So sometimes a>b, but most of the time a<b. Should only the a>b iterations be evaluated as 0?

Comment: Only the a>b iterations should be evaluated as 0.